# Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) implementation in pytorch or tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, pytorch

I found an implementation of the Kernel density estimation in scikit-learn as:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=1.0, kernel='gaussian')
kde.fit(x[:, None])
logprob = kde.score_samples(x_d[:, None])
```

The problem is I want to use Automatic differentiation to take the derivative of `logprob` w.r.t. `x`, so I need to use pytorch or tensorflow.

Is there any implementation of the KDE in pytorch or tensorflow, so I can use **AD** afterward? Or, How can I calculate the derivative of `logprob w.r.t.` x with scikit-learn?

Comment: did you find anything yet? I'm actually also looking for some kde with auto diff..

Comment: Unfortunately, No

Comment: I'm trying to mimic KDE of sklearn in tensorflow with `tf.math`. According to the definition, the high-dimensional kernel density estimation must be multiplied together and will inevitably overflow. The most problem is that, sklearn's KDE function make a special boundary (which I havn't know how to mimic) to deal with overflow, making its output still meaningful value. However, in my mimic, only 'inf' output in high-dimensional  density estimation. The only good thing is that when the dimension is not very high, the mimic output is the same with sklearn's KDE's output.

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2023**

There is a TensorFlow implementation available in [zfit](https://zfit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/components/models/kde_models.html). This is a library that offers PDFs and is based on top of TensorFlow.

**JAX now has an implementation**

Since you mentioned autograd, JAX is capable of both autograd and jit compilation and offers now the [gaussian KDE](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) function that also SciPy implements.

*Update*

Just to mention, there are also converters that may work, i.e. [tf2jax](https://github.com/deepmind/tf2jax) and the other way around.

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpfull. But I face problem install jax for windows, not easy

Comment: Yes, JAX barely supports windows. My recommendation is - honestly - to do the coding (especially data analysis etc) under Linux ([dual boot](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/dual-boot-linux) for example). I find that's the only longterm solution to get this stuff reliably running (not only JAX...).